# Good flowchart for which ML model to use given characteristics of the dataset?

Tags: model-selection

There are so many ML models to choose from. Looking for a flow chart that someone may have created or come across that helps you decide which ML model(s) to use.

Here is some of the possible flow chart split criteria I have to wittle down which ML models I should use:

1. Regression or classification problem?
2. Unsupervised or supervised?
3. Who is the audience. Higher focus on explainability or not?
4. Dataset has lots of outliers?
5. Y outcome variable inbalanced or not?
6. Small or big dataset. Will it take weeks or just hours to train an additional model?

Are there any I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question about a generic taxonomy for machine learning problems framing. Although in practice it is sometimes difficult to know in advance which algorithm is best to select, there are some generic rules to follow as a first approximation, like the following from [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) which covers some of your points:
[image]

About questions like imbalanced datasets, I would pay more attention on which metrics to use (e.g. Precision-Recall AUC instead of ROC AUC)...

Comment: Great infographic and advice on imbalanced datasets! However, looks like its missing a few of the most popular models - random forest, GBT, XGboost, logistic regression?

Comment: Glad to help you, nice if you can also validate it. About your comment, RF or XGBoost fall in the category of ensemble methods which is also in the chart :) You also have e.g. Logistic Regression or SVM embedded in SGD classifiers: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I guess I've never heard them explicitly called `SGD classifiers`!